# How do I read from a file and store it into an array of structures?

Tags: c

I have a file with the data:

```
30 101 201 35
31 102 203 35
31 103 202 35
32 103 201 50
33 102 203 40
33 103 202 105
33 101 201 70
```

And a structure:

```
struct data
{
    int day;
    int emp;
    int pro;
    int sal;
};
```

I want to read the entire file and store it to a structure array and then print it. This is what I have:

```
int main()
{
    FILE *file=NULL;
    struct data salesarr[10];
    int i;

        file=fopen("Sales Report.txt","r");
        //Error Function
        if(file == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error!");
            exit(1);
        }
        
            for(i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                fscanf(file,"%d %d %d %d",salesarr[i].day,salesarr[i].emp,salesarr[i].pro,&salesarr[i].sal);
                printf("%d %d %d %d\n",salesarr[i].day,salesarr[i].emp,salesarr[i].pro,salesarr[i].sal);
            }

        }
```

I'm aware there's simpler ways to read and print the entire file, but I want to put it to a structure array so I can do other stuff with it, like sorting.

Comment: The main problems I see is that there are less than `10` records in the file, that you don't check what `fscanf` [returns](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value), and that you need to keep track of the current number of *initialized* elements in the array once the loop ends.

Comment: I suggest to read the file line-by-line using `fgets` and parse the resulting string with `sscanf`  instead of using `fscanf`. `fgets` will return `NULL` on EOF or error. Check the return value of `sscanf` (or `fscanf`) to find out if the expected number of 4 fields has been parsed.

Comment: `fscanf` expects pointers to the variables to store the scanned values. You pass the integer variables instead for 3 out of 4 parameters. Your compiler should warn you. If not, turn up warning level. For GCC use `-Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to do it using fgets and sscanf.